# display from database

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

while displaying address from database I have added `,` at the end of each value. when last value of address in empty am getting  `,` along with the last value. But I don't want that. Can any one help?

```
if ($Fetch['addr']!=''){
    echo $Fetch['addr'].',';
```

it is displaying

```
address,city,postalcode
```

if i remove postalcode it displayes

```
address,city,
```

but i don't need `,` at the end when any of the value is not provided

Comment: Just remove them before entering into database

Comment: put your stuff in an array and use `implode` to concatenate values with `,` that way there is no trailing comma.

Comment: thank u for all who answered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the output in a variable do not echo directly with `if` as you are doing and then use below function and finally print them after applying `rtrim` on the `$str`.

string should be stored in `$str` with all the `if`'s

```
if ($Fetch['addr']!=''){
    $str.=$Fetch['addr'].',';
```

This will remove last comma

```
echo $clean = rtrim($str,',');
```

Answer (score 3):

Insert your value in array and at the end of it use [`join`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) to convert array to string with:

```
$array[] = [Your Value Here];

$string = join ( ',' , $array )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Substr() It will really helps!

```
$str = "abcde,";
$str = substr($str,'',-1);
```

Now this will remove , from String.